# How to link traces between subplots in R Plotly with shared Y axis so that hoverinfo appears on both?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I've managed to create a figure made of two subplots which are horizontal bar charts (lollipops), side-by-side, with a shared Y-axis:

[image]

However, I'd like each pair of horizontal lollipops to be linked between them so that when you hover over one the hovertemplate info is shown for both instead of just one. Is there a way to do this using Plotly R, perhaps a custom JS function or something like that? I assume it's not easily possible using the legend group option.

So far I've tried these two approaches and none of them do what I want:
[R plotly link subplots so that multiple tooltips shown on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561931/r-plotly-link-subplots-so-that-multiple-tooltips-shown-on-hover)
[How to facet a plot_ly() chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103196/how-to-facet-a-plot-ly-chart)

Here's a link to my data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6kqq4z2y6nsk2g/plotly_data.RData?dl=0

And my code so far:

```
custom_hover_t <- "%{x:.2f}%"
custom_hover_c <- "%{x:.2f}%"

t <- plot_ly(data = datos) %>%
  
            #Barras tamaño
            add_trace(x = ~T2019, y = ~EjeX, 
                      type = 'bar',
                      width = 0.02,
                      marker = list(color = ~color),
                      orientation = "h",
                      hoverlabel = list(bordercolor="white"),
                      hovertemplate = custom_hover_t
            ) %>%
            
            add_trace(x = ~T2019, y = ~EjeX, 
                      type = 'scatter',mode = "markers",
                      marker = list(color = ~color, size = 7),
                      hoverlabel = list(bordercolor="white"),
                      hovertemplate = custom_hover_t
            ) %>%
  
            plotly::layout(
              xaxis = list(title     = NULL,
                           autorange = T,
                           zeroline  = T,
                           showline  = F,
                           autotick  = FALSE,
                           tickmode  = "array",
                           showgrid  = T,
                           showticklabels = F,
                           titlefont = list(color="transparent")
              ),
              yaxis = list(title     = NULL,
                           visible   = FALSE,
                           autorange = TRUE,
                           visible   = FALSE,
                           zeroline  = FALSE,
                           showline  = F,
                           showgrid  = FALSE,
                           ticklen = 0,
                           titlefont = list(color="transparent")
              ), #para mostrar solo 2 decimales al hacer hover en un punto
              showlegend = F#,
              #margin = list(l = 1)
            )

c <- plot_ly(data = datos) %>%            
           #Barras tamaño
           add_trace(x = ~CambioRel, y = ~EjeX, 
                     type = 'bar',
                     width = 0.02,
                     marker = list(color = ~color),
                     orientation = "h",
                     hoverlabel = list(bordercolor="white"),
                     hovertemplate = custom_hover_c
           ) %>%
           
           add_trace(x = ~CambioRel, y = ~EjeX, 
                     type = 'scatter',mode = "markers",
                     marker = list(color = ~color, size = 7),
                     hoverlabel = list(bordercolor="white"),
                     hovertemplate = custom_hover_c
           ) %>%
                  
           plotly::layout(
           xaxis = list(title     = NULL,
                        autorange = T,
                        zeroline  = T,
                        showline  = F,
                        autotick  = FALSE,
                        tickmode  = "array",
                        #tickvals  = ~Etiqueta,
                        showgrid  = T,
                        showticklabels = F,
                        titlefont = list(color="transparent")
           ),
           yaxis = list(title     = NULL,
                        visible   = FALSE,
                        autorange = TRUE,
                        visible   = FALSE,
                        zeroline  = FALSE,
                        showline  = F,
                        showgrid  = FALSE,
                        #ticks     = "outside",
                        #ticksuffix = ticks_pct(),
                        #showticklabels = TRUE,
                        ticklen = 0,
                        titlefont = list(color="transparent")
           ), #para mostrar solo 2 decimales al hacer hover en un punto
           showlegend = F#,
           #margin = list(l = 1)
         ) 


fig <- subplot(t, c, shareY = TRUE)

fig
```

I'd really really appreciate any help you can give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared hoverinfo across subplots is [not yet available in plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4896).

However, you could use `hovermode = 'y unified'` in a single plot across different traces:

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~2:4, y = ~4:6, text = ~LETTERS[4:6], name = "yaxis data", mode = "lines+markers", type = "scatter", hovertemplate = "<b>%{text}</b><extra></extra>")
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~4:6, y = ~4:6, name = "yaxis 2 data", mode = "lines+markers", type = "scatter")
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~6:8, y = ~4:6, name = "omit_hoverinfo", mode = "lines+markers", type = "scatter", hoverinfo='skip')

fig <- fig %>% layout(
  hovermode = 'y unified' # alternativ: hovermode = 'y'
)

fig
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, I redid my plot to use the "y unified" option. Is there a way, however, to omit a trace from the Hoverinfo that appears? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't seem to omit the trace from the y unified view though, the trace is still shown, just without any info. Is there a way to omit the trace altogether?

Comment: You asked to omit a trace from the Hoverinfo. That is what happens when using `hoverinfo='skip'`. Please see the screenshot.

Comment: Could you let me know which plotly package version you're using? I'm running the sample code you provided and I can't replicate the screenshot you've shared. When I say the trace is still shown, I mean the trace is still show in the hoverinfo unified view (just without the corresponding info on the value number) Thanks.

Comment: R plotly 4.10.0 recently updated the underlying plotly.js library from v1.57.1 to v2.5.1. This includes many breaking changes. I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2077).

Comment: As an alternative try: `hovermode = 'y'`

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately I'd really like to keep the "y unified" so hopefully they'll be able to fix it soon. Again, thanks!

Comment: Installing the previous package version is another option.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that and it works like a charm in your example, but if I set hovertemplate for any of the other two traces (which I need to do bc the scale of one of them is tricked, so I need to use the "text" option) it stops working. I assume this is a bug as well?

Comment: Just added a `hovertemplate` to my answer - seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yes, I realized later that it's because I'm adding a trace in the original plot_ly() instance and the remaining two in subsequent add_traces(). If I add a hovertemplate to the original plot_ly() instance it overrides the hoverinfo = "skip". I'm unsure how to get a stacked bar plot without any data in the original plot_ly instance though, will have to keep trying. Many thanks for your help!